# How to set a WindowSize fix?

Tags: xaml, uwp, window, size

I think you dont need that much information or my code. My Problem is, that I want to start my App. Like every other App you can change the size with your mouse when the app is running. I want the complete opposite. Is it possible to set the Windowsize fix so the user can not change the size by himself?

This is what I tried. Its starting with 1280/720, but of course you can change the size of the window still.

ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(720, 1280);
                ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;

Comment: It's not possible directly in UWP

Comment: The UWP app is designed to run on different devices that run Windows 10. What you think is unreasonable. So, like @Muzib said, it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't in UWP. But what you can do is scale your view using a scale transform if your goal is to preserve the layout arrangement without doing a ton of work to design a reactive layout.